# Git Auto-merged file not showing diff

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have 2 repositories 'master' and 'submaster' , both repositories are almost same except certain files.Also individual commits are mostly done in 'master' branch.There were 2 files got updated using a single commit in 'master' branch. Inorder to keep 'submaster' branch up-to-date,I was trying to take a pull and raise a PR by using the following commands.

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b submaster_jun13 upstream/submaster
git pull upstream master
```

Only 1 file had a conflict and the other file was auto-merged.Now the auto-merged file didn't have the expected changes and also it didn't have any diff to commit. Need suggestions why the auto-merged file didn't show any diff ?

Note: I expected both the files to have conflict and ask me to resolve but i did auto-merge of that 1 file.

Comment: `master` is usually the name of a branch, not a remote...

Comment: @Dai  upstream is the name of remote , master is the name of branch

Answer (score 0):

You can view the two diffs `git` had to combine when merging that file :

```
# three dots, not a typo :
git diff upstream/submaster...upstream/master -- that/file  # changes on master side
git diff upstream/master...upstream/submaster -- that/file  # changes on submaster side
```

---

If these two diffs show that there should have been a conflict to resolve, perhaps you have `git rerere` enabled, and that conflict matches a previous resolution of yours.

Comment: i didn't enable git rerere command in my machine

Comment: ok, do you see two diff chunks that should conflict ?